# how to use regular expression to match strings followed by some keyword and multiple lines

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching, matching

I have a string like this:

```
...
xxxx
xxx

keyword1 xxxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxxx keyword2 yyyy
xxx
xxxx

xxx
...
```

where the x and y's are just random chars. I need to match the first "keyword2 yyyy" that appears after keyword1, and there may be multiple lines after keyword1. How do I write the regular expression? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^(?s).*keyword1.*?(keyword2 yyyy).*$
```

Explanation:

- ^ --> start of string
- (?s) --> Enables dot to match new lines
- .* keyword1.*? --> Matches a string that contains keyword1 preceded and succeeded by any characters doing non-greedy match
- (keyword2 yyyy) --> matches the string of your interest
- .*$ --> followed by any characters and finally end of input

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PYf7B6/2)

Comment: Thank you Pushpesh! I made a mistake in my original post. There are lines before and after the interested parts but I'm only interested in the "keyword2 yyyy" part. Now I have 'keyword1(?s).*?(keyword2.*?)\n', but this returns the whole string starts from keyword1:
keyword1 xxxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxxx keyword2 yyyy
How do I just extract the "keyword2 yyyy"?

Comment: Hey, you can't move (?s) part in middle of regex as that is a flag in regex which tells dot can match new lines. I think you are capturing whole regex match. For capturing the interested text, you need to capture group 1's content.

Comment: If I don't move the (?s) in the middle it won't match anything because there 're multiple likes between keyword1 and keyword2. How do I get capture group 1's content?

Comment: (?s) is a global flag enabler. I think you are confusing it little bit with \s. For capturing group 1's content your language must be providing some way. Like in Java, you write matcherObject.group(1). What language are you dealing with?

Comment: I'm using ANSI SQL. If I don't use (?s) it won't match the multiple lines, right?

Comment: Correct. (?s) enables a dot to match newline